# Latex fragment preview doesn't work with ImageMagick

Tags: org-mode

In org mode, previewing a particular latex fragment with `C-c C-x C-l` renders incorrectly when using ImageMagick instead of the default dvipng.

Rendering with dvipng works:

[image: dvipng]

Rendering with ImageMagick doesn't work:

[image: imagemagick]

Elisp to use ImageMagick instead of dvipng:

`(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'imagemagick)`

Note: I need to use ImageMagick because the dvipng setting doesn't respect `org-latex-pdf-process`, [as documented here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html#sec-3).

Emacs 25.0.50.1 64bit linux

ImageMagick 6.7.7

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a direction to think. Look at the function `org-create-formula-image-with-imagemagick` and try to reproduce what it does step-by-step looking at the intermediate results. I have a gut feeling it's the `"-density" dpi` or the `"-antialias"` which garbles the image.

Comment: @wvxvw Good thinking, but messing with the flags didn't change much. (SE It won't let me upvote yet)

Comment: From looking further into imagemagick documentation, it appears that there are many more options there. This can depend on many things, even on the order of the arguments. Could you update your question with what the LaTeX code you get for the PDF and the exact command line this function then generates for imagemagick? Just to make sure the problem reproduces (or not) elsewhere.

Comment: Setting `org-latex-create-formula-image-program` to `'imagemagick` works fine for me. How does the manual testing using `convert` work for you as shown in the link you posted? I haven't ever needed to tweak the imagemagick flags; it worked right out of the box. Try out in an `emacs -Q` session while requiring only `ox-latex`. Also, I am on the latest org version available on MELPA.